# php oop, class structure with many class

Tags: php, oop

how in one class use another class?
My code is correct?

```
<?php
class Country{
    function countryById($id)   {
        echo $id;
    }

}
class Validate{
    function text($id)  {
        return true;
    }

}
class Register{

    function write($name, $url, $country){
        $val = new Validate();
        $c_id = new Country();

        if(!$val->text($name))
          return false;

        $country_id = $c_id->countryById($country);
        }
}


$r = new Register();
$r->write('test', 'www.google.com', 'france');
?>
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question and add more context about what it actually is you are trying to do. Also, the code sample you provided will most likely not work as it contains syntax errors. Please post valid code so that we can answer your question properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

almost.
except $val = new Validate;
right syntax is $val = new Validate();
and include function expects string literal or variable (include ('class/myclass.php'))

Comment: `$val = new Validate;` is fine. You can omit the brackets.